# Freeing Up Partition Space

Tags: disk-usage, partitioning, disk-management

I have a 10GB Ubuntu partition and I am starting to run out of hard disk space.

- What are some large things I can remove to free up space and where are they located?

Comment: cleaning package cache with `sudo apt-get clean` and [removing the old kernels](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) would recover _some space_..

Comment: @rusty thanks but it's alright I expanded my partition space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the disk usage analyzer to figure out what is taking all the space.

*Also, I'd suggest a larger partition size. If you plan to use Ubuntu fully and use some applications, then 10 Gigs definitely won't be enough.*

Comment: thanks. this question is kind of moot because I superseded it with the following question: http://superuser.com/questions/724157/removing-failed-install-partition-of-ubuntu to extend the size of my partition.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can always manage bigger files and folders, like your movie and music collection through your main partition or an external drive, instead of coping them over to your ubuntu partition.
2. A lot of tools and application come pre-installed, that are not necessary for most users to maintain and also consume some disk space. The easiest way is to open `software-center` and browse through the single categories, to see what applications are installed and which of those you don't need [at all].
3. Furthermore you could use GUI applications, like [computer-janitor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/computer-janitor-gtk/) or [bleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/), that do a decent job in freeing up space.

   - Please use with care!!