# No space left on left on Drive after deleting everything. /dev/sda6 100% used

Tags: permissions, disk-usage, hadoop

I had recently run a script in our college exam on my computer which was specifically for 32bit(i386) but my ubuntu is amd64 , so the script wouldn't run but then I tried accessing the folders in my home folder which gave me permission denied.
    So I did a sudo chmod 777 -R /home/username , which gave me permissions to complete the test even though I was put as an exception to take my test without using the script to run successfully.
    After all this and another two days later I started facing problems of less space on my drive but I probably should have had plenty of space.
    Then it said that I have 1.4 kb space left on the system. I searched for my problem on the net and somewhere I found an answer on askubuntu which I am not able to find again. It said that, what actually happened is that the home directory should have 644 permission rather than 777 and so the files I deleted had their INODES still present along with the new files I added to the directory and hence there is no space left.
    I have removed everything from the home directory and when I try to add a file with size less than a kb it still says no space left. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
 running df  gives
    Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda6       16229452  15634864         0 100% /
    udev             1941220         4   1941216   1% /dev
    tmpfs             780000       972    779028   1% /run
    none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
    none             1949996      9732   1940264   1% /run/shm
    overflow            1024       668       356  66% /tmp
    /dev/sda3      449082364 281834708 167247656  63% /media/Acer
    /dev/sdb1      976762524 250648068 726114456  26% /media/HD-PCTU2

df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        16G   15G     0 100% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           762M  972K  761M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G   14M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
overflow        1.0M  668K  356K  66% /tmp
/dev/sda3       429G  269G  160G  63% /media/Acer
/dev/sdb1       932G  240G  693G  26% /media/HD-PCTU2

gparted Image

i.imgur.com/NK0U349.png
```

Comment: post the output of `df -h`?

Comment: It would be better if you upload gparted screenshot.Take a screenshot and then upload it to imgur.com.Finally post the uploaded link here.

Comment: I don't have space to save a screen shot :(

Comment: is there any possiblities to take the screenshot by mobile and upload it here.

Comment: Avinash, can you please let me know of what thing I should take a screenshot of. I don't what is gparted and what it is used for. I am some how able to install packages but not able to add any file anywhere.

Comment: Gparted partition editor.Open it from dash.

Comment: Hey I need atleast 10 reputation to add images here.

Comment: upload the image to imgur.com and post the link as comment.

Comment: Sorry Its becoming hard for me to post a comment here because the browser window closes automatically after some time and I have to relogin etc. I am trying mybest to upload an image. Thanks.

Comment: RED please check if this link helps: [..:: click to visit ::..](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429050/freeing-up-partition-space#comment559738_429050)

Comment: or post the link in your question.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/NK0U349.png

Comment: I had done apt-get clean earlier to clean up the apt archives. It didn't add up any space and still showed no space left.

Comment: you want how much space from which partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because of a log file taking up too much space on the disk. The file was found in the HADOOP_LOG_DIR. We can find it in /etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh. Here while configuring we setup the HADOOP_LOG_DIR.

I found them using:
find / -size +100M -ls.

Just do an rm -rf /var/log/hadoop/ . If your HADOOP_LOG_DIR points to /var/log/hadoop/ else rm -rf that particular location.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the size of `/dev/sda6` root partition,

- Boot Ubuntu live disk and click on try Ubuntu option on startup.Now open gparted partition Editor from dash.And make sure that all the partitions are unmounted.
- shrink `/dev/sda3` by right-clicking on it and select Resize/Move option.
- After shrinking, the unallocated space will be created just below to the `/dev/sda3` partition.
- Now right-click on the extended partition and select Resize option to add up the unallocated space by extending the dragger.
- Unallocated space will comes under extended partition(just below to the `/dev/sda5` partition.
- Rightclick on the `/dev/sda5` partition and select Resize/Move option.Move the dragger to extreme right and then click on Apply,so that the unallocated space comes just below to the `/dev/sda5` partition.
- Now you can be able to extend your `/dev/sda6` root partition.

See also [How to extend ext4 with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421271/how-to-extend-ext4-with-gparted) and [Extending my Root Paritition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404361/extending-my-root-paritition)

Comment: I figured out the problem few days earlier,it was related to the hadoop log files which occupied enormous space. Just needed to clean those. I did increase my partition size. Your answer was useful to some extent. I did want to give a +1 but it requires me 15pts.Thanks for helping.

Comment: @RED please post your comment as an answer.it will help others in future.